# Dominance of $[nx]$ over $n[x]$

Tags: number-theory

How to prove:

> $[nx]-n[x]\geq0$ where, $[.]$ is greatest integer function and
>   $n\in\mathbb{N}$

I know that $[nx]-n[x]=n\{x\}-\{nx\}$. But I am unable to see why this quantity is greater than $0$

Can anyone please give me some hints? Please.

Comment: Hint: $[nx]$ is defined to be the *largest* integer that's less than or equal to $nx$. Is $n[x]$ an integer that's less than or equal to $nx$?

Comment: I withdrew my comment because I liked the suggestion of @GregMartin better.  But, to do it the way I suggested, if $x=\lfloor x\rfloor +\delta$ then $\lfloor nx\rfloor =\lfloor nx +n\delta\rfloor$ and the floor function is non-decreasing.

Comment: Do you mean the floor or ceiling function? Floor of $x$ is the greatest integer less than $x$. Use $\lfloor x \rfloor$ to be unambiguous.

Answer (score 3):

Let $x=\lfloor x \rfloor + \{x\}$. We have:
$$\lfloor nx \rfloor = \lfloor n\lfloor x\rfloor +n\{x\}\rfloor \geqslant n \lfloor x \rfloor$$ since $n \lfloor x \rfloor$ is an integer. Done!

Answer (score 2):

$\lfloor nx \rfloor \ge \lfloor n \lfloor x \rfloor  \rfloor = n \lfloor x \rfloor$.